# Ionic swipe on div, how to trigger?

Tags: javascript, swipe, ionic-framework

Hello i tried to recognize swipe left/right and touch gesture on div using Ionic framework:

**Documentation:**

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipeLeft/

**Code:**

```
<div class="row" on-swipe-left="alert('right');">
          <div class="col" style="background-color: red;">.col</div>
</div>
```

But this is not working.

How can i easily recognize swipe on given element?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the event directive correctly. The issue is these directives are expecting an expression as their input. The $parse function is used to convert that expression into a function. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

In short. It will only execute functions on your scope. See this codepen for a short example.

http://codepen.io/wedgybo/pen/sgKEb

```
<div ng-controller="SwipeCtrl" class="row" on-swipe-left="alert('right');">
      <div class="col" style="background-color: red;">.col</div>
</div>



angular.controller('SwipeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.alert = function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```